# Using only javascript and css: can I enable the user to selectively display and hide divs of different classes, via a single drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, visibility

I have an html page consisting of 80-100 css-styled divs each containing a grid with an image and information about a single artwork. (Each div already has a unique Id, to enable linking-in to a specific place in the page.)

Many of the works employ several media, and I want the user to be able to make visible only artworks that use particular media.

In other words, I want to make the html page behave like a filterable database, where a single drop-down menu acts like a list of filters, and clicking on the "artworks using video" option  (for e.g.) hides all works that do not use video.

*I'm want to achieve the above with css and Javascript only.*

As I understand it:

I can make my artwork divs selectable by assigning different classes, such as ".med-drawing" ".med-video" ".med-sound" etc. There would need to be 10-12 of these classes.

Then, I'd need a way, onClick, to "*make visible* all the divs that *do have*" a particular class, AND "*make invisible* the divs that  *do not have*" that class. This, for each of 10 - 12 different classes.

I've been trying a series of Javascript "onClick + GetElementsByClass + [some visibility control]" functions assigned to different elements in a menu. I have limited javascript coding knowledge and so far I can't get anything to work.

What I really need is a bare-essentials javascript/css solution that I can modify to suit my project.

I'd be grateful for any help.

---

EDIT- 1 day later (code added below these paras):

With the help of the.marolie I now have a basic 'filter/selector' working on a test page. It can select and show/hide divs precisely as I wanted, although utilising "data-type" rather than class.

Thanks!

---

EDIT 2

I had added more to this post, but, on reflection, realised that my initial question had been perfectly answered by the.marolie. My follow-up material really constututed a different question, so I've removed it here and bumped it to a new post: [Using only JS and css: can I implement a filter, so that: clicking/tapping within a JS dropdown menu shows/hides page divs according to data-type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75463722/using-only-js-and-css-can-i-implement-a-filter-so-that-clicking-tapping-withi)

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO isn't a coding service, so you are expected to make an attempt and then we can help with specific problems. Do you have a specific question about how to reach your objective?

Comment: The post title is a specific question. If the answer to it is "yes", that would be a good to know. If the answer is "no" then I'll know not to spend time trying to solve the issue in the way I've clearly stated as my preference. Neither response would require writing any code.

I've stated specifics re. my limited understanding of how to approach my problem. It would be useful to know if I'm on the right track. Such a reponse need not incude any code, but it might point me in the direction of a useful resource where I could learn enough code to solve my problem.

Comment: If you are talking about HTML class attribute then the answer is yes and to find all the artworks in a class you can use document.querySelectorAll Have a search on MDN which is a reliable source.

Comment: You said you can't get anything to work; what have you tried? Include your code in your post and we can go from there. Open-ended questions don't work well here.

Comment: You should try what you want first, and if you have any PROBLEMS, then you can post your question on StackOverflow. However, StackOverflow is NOT a codeing service website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, one approach would be:

Add common class name and  a `data` attribute to each div based on the type of content. For eg:

```
  <div class="grid-item" data-type="text">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item" data-type="audio">
    <span>Audio</span>
  </div>
```

Once you have this, you can add a select box which will contain option with values that are same as the `data-type`. Like:

```
<select id="cstm-select" name="filter">
  <option value="text">Text</option>
  <option value="image">Image</option>
  <option value="audio">Audio</option>
  <option value="video">Video</option>
</select>
```

If you see the above code, the `value` of option contain the different `data-type` attribute values that we will be using to filter the content.

Now for the js logic, first we need to listen to the `onChange` event of our `select` element, store the selected value in a variable and then query the elements once the use selects an option using the `document.querySelectorAll()` function and pass the common class name as the function parameter so that only the elements that we need to filter will be selected.

Once queried, we can loop through each element using `forEach`, then check if the `data-type` attribute of each element against the selected filter value and if it doesn't match, add a class name to the element which will control the visibility of the element.

Also, we need to make sure that if the `data-type` matches, we remove the class name so that the element is visible when the user selects a different filter.

Combining this, here is a small fiddle. Modify the code as required for your project.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('cstm-select');
var filter;

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
  filter = select.value;

  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
  elements.forEach((el) => {
    var type = el.dataset.type.split(' ');
    if (type.includes(filter)) {
      el.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      el.classList.add('hidden');
    }

  })
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="cstm-select" name="filter">
  <option value="text">Text</option>
  <option value="image">Image</option>
  <option value="audio">Audio</option>
  <option value="video">Video</option>
</select>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item" data-type="text">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-type="audio video">
    <span>Audio / Video</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-type="video">
    <span>Video</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-type="audio">
    <span>Audio</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-type="image">
    <span>Image</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-type="text">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" data-type="text">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: As per your comment, I have modified the code to include filter functionality if there are multiple `data-type` defined for a single `grid-item`.

The logic change here is that, we define the multiple `data-type` like this - `data-type="audio video"`. Provide a space between each items or you can use a comma separator as well.

And in the js code, we first split the `data-type` using `str.split()` function which stores the values in an array like `['audio', 'video']`.

Now that we have this, all we need to do is check if the selected filter is included in the dataset array and apply or remove the class as required. Check the modified jsfiddle.

Note: Whatever separator we use in `data-type` attribute, we need to define the same separator in the js code while we split.

If we use comma, the in js, it would be:

`var type = el.dataset.type.split(',');`

Comment: Thanks so much, the.marolie for such a generous response, with lots of useful exposition as well as actual code to start from. I'll work my way through it, try to understand and adapt it as you suggest, and post back here in a day or so.

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion in a basic way, on a slimmed-down test page. A few issues immediately arise. Here's the most fundamental (using your terms):  
Many of my divs need to be selectable according to one of a number of possible "data-types". Is there a way to assign multiple data-types to a single div, in such a way that your 'cstm-select' filter will still select for only the one data-type assigned to the cstm-select option last touched)?

Comment: @DrNoKnow we can do that. I've updated the answer with explanation.

Comment: Wow. Thanks again. Just picked up your mod and will try immediately.

Comment: No problem. Do let me know if it works

Comment: The mod worked perfectly... in isolation. Am now trying to integrate the.marolie's filter/selector with my existing styled dropdown! Nearly there!? See my big post EDIT...

Comment: I credited your responses as 'the answer'. They really were very informative and useful, helping me to add a vital bit of interactivity to my project. THANKS!