# Using only JS and css, can I implement a filter, so that: clicking/tapping within a JS dropdown menu shows/hides page divs by data-type?

Tags: javascript, css, filter, dropdown

With the help of SO member the.marolie I learned how to implement a JS filter/selector [the 'demo JS filter']. I have this working perfectly on a test page: it shows/hides divs according to "data-types" assigned to them in the body html. However, the selection is made by sliding down a `<select>` dropdown list and letting go at the preferred option. That's not quite what I want.

I want to utilise my existing nav-bar dropdown ['my dropdown'] as the filter/selector. I especially want to retain the existing interactivity of my dropdown, whereby one click/tap reveals the whole of the dropdown content block, and one click outside the content block closes it.

I want the elements within my dropdown to represent various show/hide `<div>` 'options' for the html page, and enable the user to choose from these via an additional click/tap (essentially what the demo JS filter does, but at the instigation of a click/tap). Once revealed via a nav-bar click/tap, the whole dropdown content block has to stay on-screen -as it currently does- for this to be practically possible.

After making my dropdown identifiable via id="media-selector-demo" and name="filter" I was hoping that I could assign the demo JS filter's `<option>` elements to the `<a>` elements in it, and the whole thing would function like the `<select>` dropdown of the demo JS filter. I had a vague idea that using `<a>` elements might obviate the need for another `onClick` in the JS. I've tried various combinations of `<a>` and `<option>` elements, but nothing has worked yet.

Do I need another `onClick` to invoke the JS filter via my dropdown? or
Can I invoke the JS filter via 'active' `<a>` status?

I'm struggling by trial and error.

Here are what I think are the relevant sections of code pertaining to all discussed above:

**My dropdown** is based on the following code.
**JS** in the page head:

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myDropdownJS() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("navbarDROPDOWN-JS")[0].classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  var myDropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("navbarDROPDOWN-JS")[0];
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

**My dropdown** **html** in nav bar (most of the css is just design styling):

```
<span class="dropdown" onclick="myFunction()">
<a class="dropbtn navbarDROP-ICON" style="opacity:0.5; padding-top:0px;">menu</a>
<a class="dropbtn navbarDROP-TXT" style="opacity:0.5">menu&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
<a class="dropbtn navbarDROP-TXT">Career Works by Date&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
<div class="dropdown-content navbarDROPDOWN-JS" >
    <a class="tag-bgd-INSTLLN" href="#">Installations (all media)</a>
    <a class="tag-bgd-MOVIMG" href="#">Works with moving image (inc. vid/film releases)</a>
    <a class="tag-bgd-SNDMUS" href="#">...with sound and music (inc. sound/music releases)</a>
    <a class="tag-bgd-PHOTO" href="#">...with photographs</a>
    <a class="tag-bgd-DRAW" href="#">...with drawing (inc. 2D works)</a>
    <a class="tag-bgd-TXT" href="#">...with text</a>
    <a class="tag-bgd-PERF" href="#">...with performative action</a>
    <a class="tag-bgd-COLPUB" href="#">Collaborative and public works</a>
    <a class="tag-bgd-OBJDEV" href="#">>Objects, garments, devices</a>
    <a class="tag-bgd-EDPUB" href="#">Editions, publications</a>
    <a class="tag-bgd-CAREER" href="#">Career Works by Date</a>
  </div>
```

Above: the `<a href>` elements were going to contain URLs for alternatively styled pages. There is no need for these if I can enable the user to selectively show/hide parts of just this one page, via this dropdown.

The **demo JS filter** is based on the following code (via SO user the.marolie).
**JS** at page end:

```
var select = document.getElementById('media-selector-demo');
var filter;

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
  filter = select.value;
    
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.wk-date_ITEM');
  elements.forEach((el) => {
      var type = el.dataset.type.split(', ');
    if (type.includes(filter)) {
    
      el.classList.remove('hide-by-media');
    } else {
      el.classList.add('hide-by-media');
    }

  })
});
```

**Demo JS filter** **CSS**:

```
.hide-by-media {
    display: none;
}
```

**Demo JS filter** **html** in page body:

```
 <select id="media-selector-demo" name="filter">
    <option value="INSTLLN"> Installations (all media)</option>
    <option value="MOVIMG"> Works with moving image (inc. vid/film releases)</option>
    <option value="SNDMUS" >...with sound and music (inc. sound/music releases)</option>
  </select>
```

Example **div in page body** (there are 80-100 of these):

```
<!-- ++++++++++ START FULL-WIDTH LIST ENTRY '2017 STATE OF DREAD' ++++++++++ -->
<div id="state-of-dread" class="w3-container wk-date_ITEM" data-type="INSTLLN, SNDMUS">
     <div class="w3-container wk-date_TXT-IMG">
        <div class="wk-date_GRID">          
          
          <div class= "h3 wk-date_DATE"> 2017 </div>
          <div class="wk-date_TTL"><h1>State of Dread</h1></div>
         <div class="h2 wk-date_KIND-1" >Installation</div>
          <div class="p wk-date_KIND-2" ><span class="sound">Sound</span>, for x2 interconnected rooms.<br>AB, CD, EF, Solo exhibition (as trio), Ohrenhoch sound gallery, Berlin.</div>
          <div class="wk-date_IMG">
          <div class="w3-container w3-right wk-date_IMG-BOX-LSCP">
          <img src="../../imgs/INSTALLATION-EVENT/2017_dread_thmb.jpg"
          alt="'xx' by Andrew Stones, installation view, xx"></div>
          </div>
       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ++++++++++ END FULL-WIDTH LIST ENTRY '2017 STATE OF DREAD' ++++++++++ -->
```

**Demo JS filter**: **JS** at end of page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var select = document.getElementById('media-selector-demo');
var filter;

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
  filter = select.value;

  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.wk-date_ITEM');
  elements.forEach((el) => {
      var type = el.dataset.type.split(', ');
    if (type.includes(filter)) {
      el.classList.remove('hide-by-media');
    } else {
      el.classList.add('hide-by-media');
    }

  })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would need to do is change the event listener from `select, change` to `drop down element, click`. you would also need to add the values of the options from the select as data-value attributes on the drop down elements.

1 - add a data-value attribute to the elements to represent what to hide

```
 <a class="tag-bgd-INSTLLN" href="#" data-value="INSTLLN">
```

2 - target the drop down elements you want to attach the event listener to.

```
const dropDownElements = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content a')
```

3 - attach event listeners to the selected targets (PS. the e in the function stands for event, click event listener produces an event object)

```
dropDownElements.forEach((dropDownElement) => {
    dropDownElement.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        const filter = e.target.dataset.value;
    })
})
```

4 - the rest is just adding the rest of the filter used in the **demo js filter**

```
dropDownElements.forEach((dropDownElement) => {
    dropDownElement.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        const filter = e.target.dataset.value
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".wk-date_ITEM")
        elements.forEach((el) => {
            var type = el.dataset.type.split(", ")
            if (type.includes(filter)) {
                el.classList.remove("hide-by-media")
            } else {
                el.classList.add("hide-by-media")
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: step 1 isn't javascript, but an addition to the html. the rest are for the js filter script

Comment: @DrNoKnow if the solution works please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: @K i I deleted one of my previous comments by accident... and another because it was nonsense: I had misattributed the numbers of your steps in my response, as you no doubt spotted. In case others are reading: of course your Step 1 goes into the html, as you say. Your Step 2 code I put immediately before your Step 4 code, all exactly as written, within <script> tags at the foot of my page. 
The filter interactivity works perfectly, then. 
The glitchy 'click' response I reported at first was due to text being inside <span> elements within <a> elements.
THANKS SO MUCH!